# How I can insert data to table in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

The question is, I have this table: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. I need turn it so:
1 2 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 8 9. What function in MATLAB allows me do that? Or I must make it by myself?  I'm already understand my problem.

Comment: What is the pattern behind? Why are some values changed and others not?

Comment: For example i need to interpolate some values in my table. For example: 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
turns into
1 2 3 3.2 3.4 3.6 3.8 4 5 6 7 8 9

or maybe 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
turns into 
1 2 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 6.5 7 8 9

Comment: @Undermove if there is no describable pattern then you'll have to make it yourself. I think you should reword this question completely though...

Comment: What is a pattern? Can't understand, is it my task? I just have this examples.

Comment: Your example can't be the complete input. How should the code "know" which part to modify and how? There must be some other input.

Comment: Maybe, so. I have x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]. I need to turn it to x2 = [1 2 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 7 8 9]. Something looks like this: x2 = funName[x,3,6];

Comment: So your above example (`4 4.5 5.5 6`) is a typo and it should be `4 4.5 5 5.5 6`?

Comment: Oh, understand, yes this is a typo, sorry. Edit this

Comment: I think it is stupid question, but why people rate this question down?

Comment: @Daniel In any case thank you.

Comment: @Undermove: Your question is downvoted because it does not contain the required information to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess an first order interpolation is what you want. 
How to handle the funktion *interp1* is explained in the [Matlab Manual](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).